# MultipleOutputs in mapper function Hadoop version issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, multipleoutputs

I am implementing Hadoop mapreduce. My input to map is a table as shown below:

> customerid, IP, Attr , Date
>
> customer1,  IP1, attr1, date1
>
> customer2, IP2, attr1, date2

the output from the mapper should be multiple files

File 1 : IP-m-00000

> key,            value
>
> customer1_IP1   , date1
>
> customer2_IP2  , date2

File 2: Attr-m-00000

> key,  value
>
> customer1_attr1   , date1
>
> customer2_attr1 , date2

I have hadoop 2.2.0 installed and i am using the following code

```
MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput (job, "IP", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class); //  in the Driver.class
MultipleOutputs.getCollector("IP", context).collect(txtKey, txtValue); // in the Mapper.class
```

where my txtKey is customerid_$Attribute, txtValue is the date.

I have 2.8.0 installed on another personal machine and MultipleOutputs object has write functionality which was very easy to implement. MultipleOutputs.write() which is in hadoop-2.8.0 is not implemented in hadoop-2.2.0.

Any ideas on how to write multipleOutput files in hadoop-2.2.0 where we do not have MultipleOutputs.write() functionality?

If this question requires any modification, can you please comment and not close the question!

Thanks,
Guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code contains addMultiNamedOutput() method, this method is used if you have multi-level output. Use .addNamedOutput() method instead and it worked for hadoop-2.2.0.

If you want Attr-m/r-00000 , use .addNamedOutput() method.
If you want Attr-SubAttr-m/r-00000 use  .addMultiNamedOutput() method.